# Blinking letters in c++

Tags: c++

I am developing programs in c++ on linux platform (g++ compiler) . Where in one point I want my output character to blink on the terminal. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

[ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library will be of help.

Comment: Also be prepared to invest a lot more time in your terminal output as soon as you want to do things nicely.

Answer (score 3):

From looking at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Codes), the string `\e[5mfoo\e[m` produces a blinking "foo" in xterm or in the Linux console (as in Ctrl-Alt-F1). Worth noting that `gnome-terminal` doesn't respond to it (just produces a plain foo), and neither xterm nor gnome-terminal nor tty1 respond to 6 (blink rapid), at least on my system (Ubuntu 9.04).

Comment: Yes because blinking text is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

install vtoo it can help you